# How to change content/components within a js react page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To clarify I'm working a react page that would show the user one piece of content that will be displayed on the page. When the user clicks on a link to said piece of content that they would like to see on the page.

The structure of the page goes like this. There will be a navbar that is specific to the page. The navbar has links to the components/content I'm also using styled components for this project the navbar looks like this

The servantclassnavbar file.

```
import react from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
//useable react icon
import {FaCaretDown} from 'react-icons/fa'

const Navbarcontainer = styled.ul`
    background: #D3D3D3;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
`


const Dropdownbtn = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
    &:hover{
        color: cyan;
        background: grey;
        transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }
`

const Dropdowncontent = styled.div`
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
`

const Dropdownli = styled.li`
  display: inline-block;
  &:hover {
        color: cyan;
        background: grey;
        transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
  }
  &:hover ${Dropdowncontent} {
    display: block;
  }
`

const Dropdownnavlinks = styled(Link)`
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  &:hover {
    color: cyan;
    background-color: grey;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
  }
`

function Servantclassesnavbar(){

    return(
        <>
            <Navbarcontainer>
                <Dropdownli>
                <Dropdownbtn>
                    Knight Classes<FaCaretDown />
                </Dropdownbtn>
                    <Dropdowncontent>
                        <Dropdownnavlinks to="/saberclass">Saber</Dropdownnavlinks>
                        <Dropdownnavlinks to="/archerclass">Archer</Dropdownnavlinks>
                        <Dropdownnavlinks to="/lancerclass">Lancer</Dropdownnavlinks>
                    </Dropdowncontent>
                </Dropdownli>
            </Navbarcontainer>
        </>
    )
}

export default Servantclassesnavbar;
```

Here is a the page that I want to have it act as a home page for the all the other components to display their content in. You can ignore the 'Navbar' and 'sidebar' they are just navigations to other pages for this site.

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import Navbar from "../componets/navbar";
import Sidebar from "../componets/sideBar";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Servantclassesnavbar from "../servantclassescomponets/servantclassesnavbar";
import Introduction from "../servantclassescomponets/Introduction"
import Saberclass from '../servantclassescomponets/Saberclass'
import Lancerclass from '../servantclassescomponets/Lancerclass'
import Archerclass from "../servantclassescomponets/Archerclass"

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
 const Displayedserventclasscontainer = styled.div`
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    width: 95vw;
    height: 280vw;
    background: rgb(130,141,162);
    background: linear-gradient(274deg, rgba(130,141,162,0.938813025210084) 0%, rgba(66,116,150,0.6306897759103641) 50%, rgba(132,152,187,1) 100%);

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
        min-height: 230vh;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 540px){
        min-height: 320vh;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 414px){
        min-height: 350vh;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 375px){
        min-height: 415vh;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 360px){
        min-height: 450vh;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 320px){
        min-height: 530vh;
    }
 
 `;

function Servantclasses (){
    const [isOpen, SetIsOpen] = useState(false);

    function toggle (){
        SetIsOpen(!isOpen)
    }



    return(
        <>
        <Navbar toggle={toggle}/>
        <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle}/>
        <Servantclassesnavbar />
        <Displayedserventclasscontainer>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Introduction} />
                    <Route path="/saberclass" component={Saberclass} />
                    <Route path="/lancerclass" component={Lancerclass} />
                    <Route path="/archerclass" component={Archerclass} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </Displayedserventclasscontainer>
        </>
    )

}

export default Servantclasses;
```

Last here is an example of the component/content I'm trying to display on the page.

```
import react from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import sabercard from '../assets/sabercard.png'
const Maincontainer = styled.div`
    margin: auto;
    width: 75vw;
    height: 275vw;
    text-align: center;
`
const Classnameheader = styled.h1`
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;

`

const Classcardimg = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;

    > img {
        width: 15vw;
        height: 30vw;
    }
`
const Loreheadercontainer = styled.h2`
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
`
const Classlorecontainer = styled.div`
    font-size: larger;

`
       <Maincontainer>
            <Classnameheader>Saber</Classnameheader>
            <Classcardimg><img src={sabercard} alt="The Servant class card image" /></Classcardimg>
            <Loreheadercontainer>Saber Lore</Loreheadercontainer>
            <Classlorecontainer>Servants that are placed in this class are legendary figures who took up the sword in their life. 
                some are known for choosing to master their swordsmanship. others only used it briefly, but they are a Saber all the same.</Classlorecontainer>
```

At first I tried using react-router as you can see in the page file that houses all the content, and that's when I realize that react-router changes the whole page leaving a blank page. How would I make it so when I click on one the links the content with in the page's 'Displayedserventclasscontainer' will display just the content the user wants to see within that page?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Servantclassesnavbar` uses the `Link` component, it should be inside of the `Router` component as follow:

```
return(
  <Router>
    <Navbar toggle={toggle}/>
    <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle}/>
    <Servantclassesnavbar />
    <Displayedserventclasscontainer>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Introduction} />
        <Route path="/saberclass" component={Saberclass} />
        <Route path="/lancerclass" component={Lancerclass} />
        <Route path="/archerclass" component={Archerclass} />
      </Switch>
    </Displayedserventclasscontainer>
  </Router>
)
```

And any component used outside of the `Switch` will be displayed on all pages, which I think is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That didn't work I still get a blank screen.

Comment: @RandySteward do you get that on a specific route (`/` or `/saberclass` for instance)? Or on all of them?

Comment: Is the url it says /saber pass, but the content I made for it doesn't show up I just get a white screen.

Comment: Do you get any error on the console?

Comment: Everything is fine in that regard. You get what trying to do I feel like I didn't explain it properly. I just want to show content within that displayservantsclass div in that page file and use the navbar has a way for the user to navigate for the content they want to see